# use a lets encrypt certificate for another service

Tags: ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt

I have a Lets Encrypt certificate which works on my Synology NAS using a DDNS name. I want to use the certificate for another service (ejabberd) on another machine (a Raspberry Pi), that would run under the same DDNS name, but on another port.
I can download the certificate from the NAS resulting in three files:

- cert.pem (CERTIFICATE)
- chain.pem (CERTIFICATE)
- privkey.pem (RSA PRIVATE KEY)

ejbberd's configuration needs the certificate file in two places:

```
###   ===============
###   LISTENING PORTS
listen:
port:5222
[...]
certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/certfile.pem"
```

and

```
s2s_use_starttls: optional
s2s_certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/certfile.pem"
s2s_protocol_options:
  - "no_sslv3"
```

I am not sure which file to use here. I had this working, but the certificate expired.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by `cat cert.pem chain.pem privkey.pem > certfile.pem`
Here is a description and also (under appendix) a description of the certfile format. https://www.process-one.net/blog/securing-ejabberd-with-tls-encryption/